# how to implement categoris in typo3 4.7

Tags: typo3, typo3-4.7

I need to categorize my content in typo3 4.7.How can I implement the categories in typo3 4.7.From typo3 6.0.x it is possible to integrate an extension for it.Please help me if anyone knows the solution.Thanks in advance

Comment: You really shouldn't use such an old version. You really shouldn't use an unpatched web application. The upgrade system from 4.x to 6.2 (LTS) is quite simple due to a wizard, so an upgrade shouldn't be a problem. That said: You didn't state your problem thoroughly. In order to extend tables the [standard guide](https://wiki.typo3.org/Extending_typo3_tables) might help. But still: this would be more work, than an upgrade. Especially for somebody without deep TYPO3 knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, TYPO3 did not have categories before version 6.0, according to the [TYPO3 Core API documentation on system categories](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Categories/Index.html#system-categories). If you're stuck with version 4.7, you'll have to write your own category system. You might be using userFunc -- see for instance a [userFunc tutorial extension](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/browser_tut_userfunc_en). Or, you might write your own extension, essentially duplicating what was done for 6.0.